# Cucumber Support In IntelliJ Idea Community Edition?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

- I'm trying to add a .feature file for testing in a java suite for intellij. Howerver I'm unable to open the file in intellij
- Is cucumber support only available for the ultimate edition?

EDIT: I just did a fresh install and it is now working

Comment: It works but with plugin. If I'm not wrong with this one it worked: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.4
But I'm not sure, sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks Kelver, I've added that extension but it still doesn't work for me. Does it work for you?

I downloaded an EAP Ultimate edition and cucumber works there no problem. However I can't seem to get it to work in the community edition and I'm not sure if it is even supported

Comment: Actually I'm not sure too. It worked for me some time ago but I'm not sure which version if Idea I've used. 
Maybe this link can be useful:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cucumber.html

Comment: I've look at that already and trying setting up everything too. I guess it's not supported but I'm trying to find out if there are older versions if it was supported on or if it works on the community edition on 14.1 and I just have some config issue but I highly doubt it is the latter

Comment: sorry for links spam. But Intellij site actually says that it's supported in community:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: This is what is confusing because I found another [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-types-recognized-by-intellij-idea.html) where it says it is not supported:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a fresh install and feature files are now wokring! Not sure what the problem was and I'm also confused why intellij has contradicting information on their site.

See:
- [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-types-recognized-by-intellij-idea.html)

Answer (score 8):

The main cause of this problem is that you may not be specifying the file type. You can do this in the IDE settings:

[image: File Types in IntelliJ]

Comment: For some reason I had to it in Intellij 2017 Community edition and it worked for me